# How to open this FFC/FPC connector?

Tags: connector, fpc, ffc

I am working on an old minidisc player (Sony MZ-E900) and the motor is connected via this FFC/FPC cable. I have downloaded service manual for this model and for this flexbile connector there is only this info (CONNECTOR, FFC/FPC (ZIF) 8P). I usually have no problem with these types of connectors but this particular one is not easy to open and I don't want to destroy that. Do you have a tip how to open this one? My original thought was to pull the white corners forward or to the sides but it's holding tight so I need to be sure which direction to pull.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: These are usually opened by one of two ways. Either lift the brown part with your fingernail or pull it horizontally in the direction of the cable. This one looks like the former though

Comment: It gave quite a resistance but lifting it up worked fine! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

The brown latch should just be able to pull up, the white part of the connector looks fixed. Be careful as older plastic can become slightly brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Put your fingernail above the flex going in the connector in the very middle and pull up. The latch should pivot up.

Be mindful to apply force to the midpoint to avoid breaking the hinge point, it's also described in many connector datasheets.